# jQuery code to select three different options from a list with three drop downs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have three distinct dropdown boxes, each one contain a list that is common to that three boxes. My need is to filter the list like,

> when user selects an option in the first dropdown, then he goes to
>   next, he shouldn't get the option in the list the is selected earlier
>   in the first dropdown.

This is the image showing two dropdowns, I need three of them.
  [image: this is the image for two ddwns, but actully i need three of it.]

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function cleanMonth(ddl) {
            var val = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

        //Clear all items
        $("#ddlMonth2 > option").remove();

        //Add all options from dropdown 1
        $("#" + ddl.id + "> option").each(function () {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.text = this.text;
            opt.value = this.value;
            document.getElementById("ddlMonth2").options.add(opt);
        });

        //Remove selected
        $("#ddlMonth2 option[value='" + val + "']").remove();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, and what have you tried?

Comment: And please don't shout. maybe there are more appropriate formatting options...

Comment: This is code i have..

Comment: What is happening with the snippet you already have? Is it working partially? Any error shown in browser console?

Comment: It works for the static content, but not for the dynamic content, I have the list comes from the database, I'm displaying it through the php script. I'm not much familiar with jQuery or JS, pls help me to improve this..

Comment: @Naveen can you create a JSFiddle? Thats expedite the process of solving the question...

Comment: Sorry, every one. I'm getting confused with all these. I don't get anything like you said, I need just an idea to go. Will you please?? Or I'll go back with just a disappointment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dropdown test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="first">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
  </select>
  <select id="second">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
  </select>
  <select id="third">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
  </select>

</body>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#first").on('change',function(){
             var selectedItem = $("#first").val();
             $("#second").children("option").show();
             $("#second").children("option[value^=" + selectedItem + "]").hide();
        });
        $("#first ,#second").on('change',function(){
             var selectedItem = $("#first").val();
             var selectedItem2 = $("#second").val();
             $("#third").children("option").show();
             $("#third").children("option[value^=" + selectedItem + "]").hide();
             $("#third").children("option[value^=" + selectedItem2 + "]").hide();
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

This code will work...

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Apmeena . I have got it. Sorry for making trouble. Because I'm new to this. Thanks for the patience.